# You are attempting to call methods on an uninitialized goal handle

Tags: ros, action, action-server, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've written a simple action server & client. However I am getting this error message from the server when calling the goal:

```
[ERROR] [1500532897.640619656]: You are attempting to call methods on an uninitialized goal handle
```

This is the simple server code - what am I missing?:

Thanks
Mark

```
 FibonacciAction(std::string name)

  : action_name_(name)
  , as_(name, false)
    
  {
    action_name_ = name;
    as_.registerGoalCallback(boost::bind(&FibonacciAction::goalCb, this));
    as_.registerPreemptCallback(boost::bind(&FibonacciAction::preemptCb, this));
    as_.start();
  }

void goalCb()
{
  bool success = true;
  goal_ = *(as_.acceptNewGoal());   if( as_.isActive() ) {
  if(success)
  {
    result_.text = "goalCb Succeeded";
    ROS_INFO("%s: goalCb Succeeded", action_name_.c_str());
    // set the action state to succeeded
    as_.setSucceeded(result_);
  }
}

void preemptCb()
{
  bool success = true;

  // push_back the seeds for the fibonacci sequence
  if(success)
  {
    result_.text = "preemptCb Succeeded";
    ROS_INFO("%s: preemptCb Succeeded", action_name_.c_str());
    // set the action state to succeeded
    //as_.setSucceeded(result_);
    as_.setPreempted( result_, result_.text );
  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266887/you-are-attempting-to-call-methods-on-an-uninitialized-goal-handle/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem was I needed to add the following line to the goalCb callback (code above now updated)

```
goal_ = *(as_.acceptNewGoal());
```

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2017-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2